# Would consuming a grey troll still make the Bergens happy?

Tags: trolls-2016

In [Trolls (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolls_(film)), the Bergens believe they must consume Trolls to be happy.

We've seen that Trolls can exist in two states - a colorful 'happy' form (like Poppy), and and a grey 'unhappy' form (like Branch).

Towards the end of the movie,

> All of the Trolls briefly turn grey as they believe their situation was hopeless and they were all about to be consumed.

So would consuming a grey, unhappy Troll (like Branch) still make the Bergens happy? Or would being a grey Troll actually mute the effect and save one from being consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't immediately apparent what *physiological* benefit eating a Troll has on a Bergen (or why doing so causes them to feel happy) so it's hard to state ***definitively*** that a grey troll is going to be less or more happy-causing than a coloured Troll. That being said, we can examine this in a little more detail and draw a judgement.

The [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32326641-trolls) mentions that the trolls *taste* delicious.

> The other Bergens’ beady eyes widened in wonder. “Show us!” one of
> them roared. The first Bergen led them all back to the Trolls’ happy
> forest, running the whole way. **The Bergens began snatching the
> mouth-sized Trolls out of the trees and gobbling them up. Delicious!
> Scrumptious! Why would the Bergens ever want to be anywhere else? This
> forest full of Trolls was the tastiest place in the world!**

And you get the happiness 'hit' when the troll enters the gastrointestinal tract, suggesting that ***digestion*** of the troll is key to the process.

> The Bergen grabbed the Troll and popped him in his mouth! GULP! The
> giant beast swallowed the little Troll whole. **The second the Troll hit
> his tummy, the Bergen experienced intense feelings he’d never felt
> before—Joy! Delight! Bliss!**—each with an exclamation point. These were
> words he’d never used, but they seemed to describe the sensations he
> was having.

Assuming that the Bergen is literally consuming the Troll's *happiness*, then **eating a grey troll would have much the same effect** since, we learn from Poppy (and then Branch), **happiness is found within each troll, regardless of their current state of mind**.

> Branch knew it didn’t make much sense to be happy when they were
> trapped in a pot, about to be served to a bunch of hungry Bergens. “I
> know,” he said. “But you were right—**happiness is in me.** And you helped
> me find it.”